# Escape double quotes in input value

Tags: php

I have an input field where the value echoed in PHP is encoded with a UTF-8 charset

```
<input value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($data["title"]); ?>" type="text">
```

Sample value:

> "पीला सितारा పసుపు నక్షత్రం yellow star!"

The double quotes that are appearing in the text are preventing the value from being displayed.

I have tried this, but it is not working.

```
<input name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($data["title"])); ?>"  class="width9" type="text"> type="text">
```

Comment: Just use `htmlspecialchars($data["title"])` that should do the trick.

Comment: htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") is what we are using

Comment: The function you are using is doing the opposite of what you want. You should be using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: with htmlspcialchars i get this "&#2346;&#2368;&#2354;&#2366; &#2360;&#2367;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366; &#3114;&#3128;&#3137;&#3114;&#3137; &#3112;&#3093;&#3149;&#3127;&#3108;&#3149;&#3120;&#3074; @TiMESPLiNTER

Comment: @tomhre: I tried htmlentites before and with that i get this: "&#2346;&#2368;&#2354;&#2366; &#2360;&#2367;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366; &#3114;&#3128;&#3137;&#3114;&#3137; &#3112;&#3093;&#3149;&#3127;&#3108;&#3149;&#3120;&#3074;

Comment: and have you tried the whole of my code?, also is there a chance that before you call my code your characters have been encoded in some way already?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you do it the wrong way around. You try to decode encoded strings. But you have to encode the string.

So you need

```
htmlspecialchars($data["title"])
```

and not

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($data["title"])
```

Because `htmlspecialchars_decode()` decodes a htmlspecialchars encoded string.

Comment: with htmlspcialchars i get this "&#2346;&#2368;&#2354;&#2366; &#2360;&#2367;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366; &#3114;&#3128;&#3137;&#3114;&#3137; &#3112;&#3093;&#3149;&#3127;&#3108;&#3149;&#3120;&#3074;

Comment: I am expecting this as my output: "पीला सितारा పసుపు నక్షత్రం yellow star!"

Comment: I don't know which PHP version you use but for me with PHP 5.5 I get `&quot;पीला सितारा పసుపు నక్షత్రం yellow star!&quot;` If you are below PHP 5.4 you can run into a charset problem.

Comment: I am using 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @Paulie I would recommend you to upgrade to PHP 5.4 or 5.5. If this is not possible you can check the manual page for [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php) how to work around the charset problem.

Answer (score -1):

htmlspecialchars($string) should work, so should htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8") and htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")

i wonder if your issue is not actually that you are not specifying the meta charset in your final page

some code for you to test

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['string_to_process'])) { $string = "enter your string"; } else { $string = $_POST['string_to_process']; }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/encoding.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="string_to_process" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        RESULTS:
        WITHOUT ESCAPING : <input type="text" value="<?php echo($string) ?>" /><br />
        FOR htmlspecialchars($string): <input type="text" value="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($string)) ?>" /><br />
        FOR htmlentities($string): <input type="text" value="<?php echo(htmlentities($string)) ?>" /><br />
        FOR htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8"): <input type="text" value="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")) ?>" /><br />
        FOR htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"): <input type="text" value="<?php echo(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")) ?>" /><br />

    </body>
</html>
```

hope it helps dude, encoding can be a pain

EDIT:

yeah i just tried it without

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

and it was messed up , include the above and all will be peachy

TH

Comment: That didn't work for me. I already had the charset defined. Here is the raw JSON that I am getting -> "title": "\"&#2346;&#2368;&#2354;&#2366; &#2360;&#2367;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366;\""

Comment: @Paulie you have not mentioned json before, can you edit the question and provide all the code that prepares json response